# Why have multiple products for an API in Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I found this API that has two products:

[image]

What's the point of having two products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about gateways but can help with multiple products.

Assume you have `cart service` which is in your APIM and its require apim key. Now lets assume you have many other services which will use it. So the way I am doing it i would create product per consumer service and add `cart service` to it along with other services you need to call from that service. So this way you will get Subscription key on consumer level.

This way you can:

- rotate keys
- apply different restrictions like rate limit and so on

To sum up, multiple products are for you to group your consumer and control which api they can call, and in UI each API where it has been used.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a separate question for gateways:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601421/what-is-a-gateway-in-azure-apim