# What is a gateway in Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a gateway assigned to my API called "Managed".

[image]

What is a gateway and how does it affect this API?

Does it have anything to do with the Gateways page in APIM? There is no "Managed" gateway listed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a gateway and how does it affect this API?

The  **[API gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts#overview)**  is the endpoint that:

```
-   Accepts API calls and routes them to your backends.
-   Verifies API keys, JWT tokens, certificates, and other credentials.
-   Enforces usage quotas and rate limits.
-   Transforms your API on the fly without code modifications.
-   Caches backend responses where set up.
-   Logs call metadata for analytics purposes.
```

> Does it have anything to do with the Gateways page in APIM? There is
> no "Managed" gateway listed:

The Gateways Page in APIM is to create [Self-hosted gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview) which  enable you to efficiently and securely manage APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds from a single API Management service in Azure.

For more information, you can refer this [Azure API Management documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/).